# HTML Form data to MySQL using Node JS not working

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js, forms

I have been practicing with a simple html form to mysql using nodejs, but it doesnt seem to work, the html is called index.html and my nodejs file is called test.js, here is my code:

My html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>email test form</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="/data">
<label for="email">Voer je email in </label> <input type="email" 
name="email"></input>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<script src="test.js"></script>

</body>
</html>\
```

My javascript for node js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mysql =  require('mysql');
var bodyParser = require ('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(express.static('public'));

var con = mysql.createConnection({
host: "localhost",
user: "root",
password: "Bionicle123!",
database: "account"
});

con.connect(function(err){ 
if (err) throw err;
console.log("Je bent verbonden aan de database!");
});

app.post("/data", function(req, res) {
var userEmail = req.body.email;

console.log(userEmail);

var sql = "INSERT INTO persoon (email) VALUES (?)";
con.query(sql, userEmail, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Failed ah mattie!");
    } else {
        console.log("Gelukt ah mattie!");
    }
});
});
```

Comment: "it doesnt seem to work" is [an unhelpful description of the problem](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/). What happens? Are there error messages? What does `console.log(userEmail);` log? What does the callback function log?

Comment: It just doesn't work, when i type an email in the form and submit it, it doesnt go to the mysql database, console.log(userEmail) doesnt show anything.

Comment: That suggests the browser is requesting the wrong URL. Look at the Network tab in the browser's developer tools.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at test.js:1

Comment: I can't think of any version of Node.js which doesn't support `require`. You must be trying to run your script in something that isn't Node.js.

Comment: Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/newuser - this is what i get now when i removed required, when i try to submit my form, i also get this error on the page itself: ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND.

Answer (score 0):

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at test.js:1

You've tagged this question [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js).

You need to run your JavaScript **using Node.js**.

Download it from https://nodejs.org/en/ , then install it, then run `node test.js`.

> Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/newuser

You need to load your HTML document from the webserver that you write using Node.js. Otherwise the `action` URL won't point to the right place.

… but first you need to finish writing the web server. Look at [the Hello World example](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html) for Express.js (which you are also using).

You need to call `listen`. That will give you a URL you are point the browser to.

Comment: i have installed nodejs already, it works when i  try to manually type in data from the js file to the mysql, but now i'm trying to get the html input to nodejs to mysql to work.

Comment: @Pakjethee — Then the second half of the answer should solve the problem.

Comment: now i get this error in chrome network : HTTP ERROR 405 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Comment: It shouldn't do. You have `app.post("/data"` which matches `<form method="post" action="/data">`. Again, check the Network tab, see if there is anything wrong about the request.

Comment: was i supposed to set it up to localhost:8080? When i look at my mysql workbench i see that the port is 3306

Comment: Two services can't share a port. Your HTTP server and database server need to run on different ports. Which ones they are doesn't really matter.

Comment: its still not working, no idea how any of this works :/